# Cannot download playlist with youtube-dl; ExtractionError

Tags: youtube-dl

I'm trying to download a YouTube playlist to my local computer, but `youtube-dl` constantly returns the below error after trying to download the first video from the playlist:

```
ExtractorError: Could not find JS function u'xm'; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

`youtube-dl` reports its version as `2016.02.22`, if relevant.

How can I solve this issue and download my videos?

Comment: @Ruud I counter that. The question you linked says to check the version, and I have the latest version. I have also used quotes as suggested. Therefore, the question you linked does not resolve my issue, and is not a duplicate.

Comment: The latest version downloads this playlist with  no issues. The command `youtube-dl --version` should show: 2016.12.22

Comment: @UltraLuminous Are you speaking on OP's behalf? If so, then notice the part where it says "youtube-dl version 2016.02.22" in OP's output; clearly outdated. If not, and you are convinced your problem is _not_ a duplicate, then please post a new question with the exact details.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by you having a (relatively) old version of `youtube-dl` installed on your computer. YouTube's software changed, causing some various parts of the site, specifically the `xm` script, to be removed. The traceback essentially states this:

```
ExtractorError: Could not find JS function u'xm'
```

In order to remedy this issue, you should update your version of `youtube-dl` to the latest present in the software repositories.

Simply run these two commands to (first) update your package cache, and (second) update `youtube-dl`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install youtube-dl
```

Comment: I got that error with the repository versions, in 16.04. To solve it, I had to install the latest, as instructed [here](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl).